# Return PID By Name

Tags: c++, process, return, pid, snapshot

I am trying to return process ID, and I have this code. What I am doing wrong?

Code is:

```
DWORD GetProcId(char* ProcName)//Get ProcessId By Name
{
    PROCESSENTRY32   pe32;
    HANDLE         hSnapshot = NULL;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

    if( Process32First( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) )
    {
        do{
            if( strcmp( pe32.szExeFile, ProcName ) == 0 )
            {
                return pe32.th32ProcessID;
            }
        }while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) );
    }

    if( hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        CloseHandle( hSnapshot );
    return 0;

}
```

And the error is `'strcmp' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'`

How I can fix it, I tried few different conversions but couldn't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to compare a wide character string with a narrow character string. Since `ProcName` is the narrow character string, it must be that `pe32.szExeFile` is a wide character string. Not surprising since Windows uses wide characters internally. You should change `char* ProcName` to `wchar_t* ProcName`, and use `wcscmp` instead of `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

`pe32.szExeFile` is apparently a `WCHAR` string, rather than a normal `char *` C string.  You will need to convert it before comparing.  Alternately, convert `ProcName` to a `WCHAR` string and then use a wide string comparison function.

A quick check of the [Visual Studio documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx) shows that you might be looking for the `wcscmp` function.

Comment: +1 For converting ProcName to a wchar*, OP should go ahead and declare most strings wchar if he is going to be dealing with the winapi for a while.